# Adding a border to website - tried everything but can't get it right

Tags: css

Any help with this would be highly appreciated. How do I add a border around my entire site? I've just started learning HTML and CSS but I haven't discovered how to do it. The writing on my website is too wide and I'd like it to look neater and trim - like this one. http://www.millcreekconstruction.biz/.

I would just appreciate one code to copy and paste to see that it actually works, and then I can edit the style and colour. I just have no idea what and where exactly to put the HTML and CSS codes. i thought the HTML goes undeneath "title" and the CSS for a border inside body - but nothing I try ever works.

Here is the first part of the html for my site:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" class="no-js">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<script>(function(html){html.className = html.className.replace(/\bno- 
js\b/,'js')})(document.documentElement);</script>
<title>It &#8211; Built with SitePad</title>
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="It &raquo; Feed" 
href="feed/" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="It &raquo; Comments 
Feed" href="comments/feed/" />


<link rel='stylesheet' id='this-style-css'  href='css/style.css' 
type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='sitemush-fonts-css'  
href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 


    <style type="text/css">.recentcomments a{display:inline 
!important;padding:0 !important;margin:0 !important;}</style>
    </head>

<body class="home page page-id-6 page-template-default">
<div id="page" class="site container-fluid">
<div class="site-inner">
```

Comment: I'd try and stick away from using `!important` unless you have to use it. This can lead to confusion for a future you troubleshooting, or even someone else that may use/help you with your code.

Answer (score 2):

The question is kind of ambiguous, but I guess you are either trying to put a border around the whole page or its content.

The first is really simple:

```css
#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  right: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  outline: 4px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay"></div>
```

You can edit the values that are now set to `4px`, and you can also change the color and the line type (`dashed`, `dotted`, etc.)

The second alternative is even simpler:

```css
#page {
  /* IDK if you have already applied the styles to position it, but I assume you have */
  outline: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <p>Your content, whatever it is</p>
</div>
```

Again, you can edit the line width, color and type.

Another idea, since I see that you are probably using Bootstrap (because I'm a wizard and totally not because I've noticed you used the `container-fluid` class), a better alternative could be to just use a [card](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/card/) and put your website content in it